install extras groups when installing package via poetry and github
lets say I have some internal utils package with the following pyproject (edited down from a real one so might not strictly work itself)
[tool.poetry]
name = "myutils"
version = "0.999.123"
description = "has utility functions to be installed on all downstream repos"
authors = ["me@company.com>"]
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"
pandas = "^2.1.3"

[tool.poetry.group.visualisation.dependencies]
plotnine = "^0.12.4"


[tool.poetry.group.types-stubs.dependencies]
google-auth-stubs = "^0.2.0"
pandas-stubs = "^2.1.1.230928"
db-dtypes = "^1.1.1"


[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"


so when Im working on the myutils package I can install this as poetry install --all-extras and it will pick up the stubs to pass mypy checks and also the visualisation libraries.
Lets then say I have some downstream repo in which I also use poetry to manage dependencies:
[tool.poetry]
name = "downstreamrepo"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "this is where I do the work"
authors = ["me@company.com>"]
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"
myutils = { git = "https://github.com/company/utilsrepo"}

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"

that will install the utils package and set me up for work. However, ideally I would also ensure that all stubs package are installed on all the downstream repos which are likely to have similar static analysis. Same goes for visualisation libraries- basically I just want to standardise across our repos as much as possible.
I feel like I want to do something like
myutils = { git = "https://github.com/company/utilsrepo", extras = ["visualisation"]}

for example. However, this doesn't pick up the libraries under the [tool.poetry.group.visualisation.dependencies] grouping.
What is the neatest way to do what I'm aiming at here?
